# Place Bullets in Text Box Powerpoint C++/CLI

Tags: .net, c++-cli, powerpoint, office-interop

I am placing a text box on a slide with my program, but I want to have bullets in the text box. I cannot seem to find how to do this? Say I have the text in a string:

```
Hey \rIt is cold
```

How do I turn that into bullets like:

```
 - Hey 
 - It is cold
```

I have found:

```
NewSlide->Shapes[1]->TextFrame->TextRange->ParagraphFormat->Bullet->Character = 8226;
```

But now the issue is how do I change the indentation of the second line I have tried

```
txtRange->Paragraphs(1,1)->IndentLevel = 2;
txtRange->Paragraphs(2,1)->IndentLevel = 3;
```

But it does not change the indentation at all when my PPT shows up, but in my code when I debug it says there is a different indentation? How do I use the Paragraphs method to change the indentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ParagraphFormat.Bullet` property is read-only, however it is still a full-fledged object that has access to other objects such as `Character`. You can insert a bullet character using `NewSlide->Shapes[1]->TextFrame->TextRange->Paragraphs[1]->ParagraphFormat->Bullet->Character = 8226`. (`8226` is the Unicode character value). There is also the `Bullet.Type` property where you can set an enumeration for example: `Bullet.Type = ppBulletUnnumbered`

You can set the `IndentLevel` of the bulleted paragraph with `NewSlide->Shapes[1]->TextFrame->TextRange->Paragraphs[1]->IndentLevel = {yourInteger1through5}`

Side note: In my experience, if you have a lot of work to do with programming Office documents, instead of fighting with its object model, it is best to ditch Interop and use OpenXML.

Comment: Did this not work for you? I admit, I have not tested this with C++ CLI, but I can, if this isn't working for you.

Comment: Just to edit this a little for what worked for me to add a bullet: `NewSlide->Shapes[picsAdded+1+BOOL_TITLE_ON_SLIDE]->TextFrame->TextRange->ParagraphFormat->Bullet->Character = 8226;` Now to indent I am not sure how to get it to work. I have tried `NewSlide->Shapes[picsAdded+1+BOOL_TITLE_ON_SLIDE]->TextFrame->TextRange->ParagraphFormat->Bullet->Character = 8226;`. but `Paragraphs` requires start and end and I have tried `NewSlide->Shapes[picsAdded+1+BOOL_TITLE_ON_SLIDE]->TextFrame->TextRange->Paragraphs(1,1)->IndentLevel = 5;` but cannot seem to get it to work.